# Mono.Cecil: get implementation of abstract method

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, mono.cecil

I'm using Cecil to inspect my program. It is working really great with one exception. How can I use Cecil to find the implementation of an abstract method?

### 1. Example of code to inspect

This is an example of code where the method *CallingType::CallAbstractMethod()* makes a call to *ImplementingType::MyMethod()*.

```
public abstract class AbstractBase
{
    public abstract bool MyMethod();
}

public class ImplementingType : AbstractBase
{
    public override bool MyMethod()
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public class CallingType
{
    public void CallAbstractMethod()
    {
        var implementingType = new ImplementingType();
        var result = implementingType.MyMethod();
    }
}
```

### 2. The problem

When I use the Cecil code below to inspect my program the variable *myMethodDefinition* represents the abstract method *AbstractBase::MyMethod()* instead of *ImplementingType::MyMethod()*. The later is the method that I would like to find. Just reading the source code it is obvious that the method *CallAbstractMethod* is actually calling *ImplementingType::MyMethod()*.

```
var assembly = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

var callingType = assembly.MainModule.Types
    .Single(t => t.Name == "CallingType");

var callAbstractMethodDefinition = callingType.Methods
    .Single(m => m.Name == "CallAbstractMethod");

var myMethodReference = callAbstractMethodDefinition.Body.Instructions
    .Where(i => i.OpCode == OpCodes.Callvirt)
    .Select(i => (MethodReference)i.Operand)
    .Single();

var myMethodDefinition = myMethodReference.Resolve();
```

### 3. My question

What can I do to get my Cecil code to find the implementing method *ImplementingType::MyMethod()*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IL from CallAbstractMethod

```
.method public hidebysig 
    instance void CallAbstractMethod () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2078
    // Code size 15 (0xf)
    .maxstack 1
    .locals init (
        [0] class ConsoleApplication1.ImplementingType, //first variable
        [1] bool
    )

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: newobj instance void ConsoleApplication1.ImplementingType::.ctor()
    IL_0006: stloc.0
    IL_0007: ldloc.0
    IL_0008: callvirt instance bool ConsoleApplication1.AbstractBase::MyMethod()
    IL_000d: stloc.1
    IL_000e: ret
} // end of method CallingType::CallAbstractMethod
```

As you can see, the callvirt OpCode is calling base class, if you want to get the real class that hold the implementation of **MyMethod** you must work like IL works, using stack.

#### So, when you run line IL_0001

> Your stack will have 1 item, that is the instance of ImplementingType

#### Then you run IL_0006

> Your stack will have 0 items, and the instance of ImplementingType will be saved in **first variable**

#### Then you run IL_0007

> Your stack will have 1 item again, that is the instance of ImplementingType

#### Then you run IL_0008,

> Call MyMethod from first item in the stack, that is the instance of ImplementingType.

So there is no way to get reference to ImplementingType just with the line IL_0008, you must "execute" the code, fake stack process and then you will be able to discover the instanced that hold the method that will execute.

The same code could be optimized, see it below:

```
.method public hidebysig 
    instance void CallAbstractMethod () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2065
    // Code size 12 (0xc)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: newobj instance void ConsoleApplication1.ImplementingType::.ctor()
    IL_0005: callvirt instance bool ConsoleApplication1.AbstractBase::MyMethod()
    IL_000a: pop
    IL_000b: ret
} // end of method CallingType::CallAbstractMethod
```

I don't know what you want to do with this, but you have the solution, csprojs, and c# class files, and you want to read the code, I would suggest you to use Roslyn to do that.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer. As you probably can guess it was not the answer I was hoping to get. But you might be right. Maybe I just have to bite the bullet.

Comment: @Pontus I knew that you would not like to know that, its sad, but its true. Have you ever considered to use Roslyn? With Roslyn it should be easier. Reading IL still possible, but with much effort.